# Static Routing over Direct Connect and VPC Peering

Tags: amazon-web-services, vmware, amazon-vpc, vpc, aws-direct-connect

We have a vmware instance hosted in our DataCentre, from which we have a AWS Direct Connect into a VPC in eu-west-2, and from there we've setup VPC peering to a different AWS account VPC in eu-west-1, as follows:

DataCentre <-- Direct Connect --> AWS London <-- VPC Peering --> AWS IE

The Direct Connect advertises the AWS London's VPCs private IP range via BGP (172.20.0.0/16). The Direct Connect is working fine, traffic between our DataCentre and this private IP range traverses the connection correctly. Similarly the VPC Peering is working correctly, I can send traffic directly instances in London (172.20.0.0/16) to instances in IE via their private IP range (172.31.0.0/16).

I want to route traffic from our DataCentre to instances in the AWS IE region over the Direct Connect and utilising VPC Peering. Specifically sending/receiving packets to a 172.31.0.0/16 IP from the VMWare instance.  Can this be achieved solely with static routes?

Problems I'm hitting:
The Direct Connect BGP seems to only advertise the VPC IP range to which it's attached, not the peered range.

Direct Connect Gateway looks to do what I need but my setup involves multiple AWS accounts so I don't believe this is a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

VPC peering does not support transit connections originating from other sources. They only support point-to-point connections, which is the reason DX BGP is advertising VPC range and not peered VPC range.

Answer (score 0):

- DX Connection or DX-Gateway doesn't support transitive routing.*(i.e VPC A and VPC B are peered and VPC A is connected via DX directly/DX-Gaetway,though it seems to be indirectly connected it doesn't allow to connect to VPC B via DX by default)*
- Direct Connect Connections doesn't support across regions but do support multiple accounts with same region. (*i.e DX location in eu-west-2 in one account can support multiple accounts for the same eu-west-2 region via Hosted VIF definition*)
- With DX-Gateway your existing DX connections can now be used across multiple regions and multiple accounts. *(Note:- From June 2019 I guess DX-Gateway can support multiple accounts)*

Try out Transit Gateway and DX-Gateway combination to simplify your networking architecture.